# There is a bug in my program. How to resolve it

Tags: javascript, php, html, debugging

I have written a code wherein if somebody selects the check box prefix to the item then he has to enter a quantity value[image]

The problem is that when he selects the checkbox to the corresponding item  and then clicks submit, instead of entering any quantity value an error is thrown, but the checkbox gets deselected and then if he enters the value in quantity box, even if he doesnt select the corresponding checkbox again the page gets submitted. This is a bug in my program but i dont know how to resolve it

Please let me know that whenever he enters a quantity value and the corresponding checkbox if not selected then an error should be thrown
Following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();     
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
Power For Light
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<style type="text/css">
.colht{
height:200px;
border: 5px solid red;
}
.colht1{
height:100px;
border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
    padding:10px;
}
.ht{
    height:200px;
}
h2,h3{
text-align: center;
}
sup{
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="document.myForm.reset();">
<?php
$bequanerr=$bechkErr="";
$bequan=$ber= $bes="";

$c=0;
//$_SESSION['postid']=rand(10, 30);
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"):

            if (!empty($_POST["bechk"])):
                $c++;
                if(empty($_POST["bequan"])):
                    echo "Hello";
                    $bequanerr="Please enter a quantity value";


                else:
                    $bequan=test_input($_POST["bequan"]);
                    if($bequan <=0):
                        $bequanerr="Please enter a valid quantity value greater than 0";

                    else:
                        if(empty($_POST["ber"])):
                            $ber=400;
                            echo "400";
                        else:
                            $ber=test_input($_POST["ber"]);

                        endif;
                        if(empty($_POST["bes"])):
                            $bes=0;
                        else:
                            $bes=test_input($_POST["bes"]);
                        endif;
                    endif;

                echo $ber." " . $bes. " " . $bequan;
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

                endif;
            endif;

endif;
function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }

?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button> 
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/powerforlight.jpg" style= "max-height:50px; margin-top:-14px; "/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a class="" href="vendorcf.php">Vendor Contact Form</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a class="" href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>



                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <form  name="myForm" class="form-horizontal " role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  autocomplete="off">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center">Bootstrap Design table</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">          
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>        
                        <th rowspan="2">Household Items</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Running Wattage

                        </th>
                        <th colspan="2">Starting Wattage

                        </th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Should start Parallely</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Should start Serially</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Typical
                        </th>
                        <th> Specific </th>


                        <th>
                            Typical
                        </th>
                        <th> Specific </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="bechk" value="be" <?php if (isset($bequan) && $bequan=="be") echo "checked";?>>Blanket, Electric
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td name="be1">400</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="ber" /> </td>
                        <td name="be2">0</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="bes" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="bequan" /> 
                        <p style="color:red"> <?php echo $bequanerr;?></p></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name= "berad" class="rdo"  value="P" <?php if (isset($bs)) echo "checked";?> />  </td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name= "berad" class="rdo"  value="S" <?php if (isset($bs)) echo "checked";?> />  </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="controls col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="reg">
                                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one `elseif` statement after `quantity >= 0` .And add one more or condition of initial if `|| !empty($_POST["bequan"])`
like below

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"):

            if (!empty($_POST["bechk"]) || !empty($_POST["bequan"])):
                $c++;
                if(empty($_POST["bequan"])):
                    echo "Hello";
                    $bequanerr="Please enter a quantity value";
                else:
                    $bequan=test_input($_POST["bequan"]);
                    if($bequan <=0):
                         $bequanerr="Please enter a valid quantity value greater than 0";
                    elseif(empty($_POST["bechk"])):
                        $bequanerr="Please check the check box";
                    else:
                        if(empty($_POST["ber"])):
                            $ber=400;
                            echo "400";
                        else:
                            $ber=test_input($_POST["ber"]);

                        endif;
                        if(empty($_POST["bes"])):
                            $bes=0;
                        else:
                            $bes=test_input($_POST["bes"]);
                        endif;
                    endif;

                echo $ber." " . $bes. " " . $bequan;
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

                endif;
            endif;

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Power For Light
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .colht{
                height:200px;
                border: 5px solid red;
            }
            .colht1{
                height:100px;
                border: 5px solid yellow;
            }
            .navbar-custom {
                background-color:#ffffff;
                color:#ffffff;
                border-radius:0;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .ht{
                height:200px;
            }
            h2,h3{
                text-align: center;
            }
            sup{
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="document.myForm.reset();">
        <?php
        $bequanerr = $bechkErr = "";
        $bequan = $ber = $bes = $bechk = $berad = "";

        $c = 0;
//$_SESSION['postid']=rand(10, 30);

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"):
            $berad = $_POST['berad'];
            if (!empty($_POST["bechk"])):
                $bechk = $_POST["bechk"];
                $c++;
                if (empty($_POST["bequan"])):
                    echo "Hello";
                    $bequanerr = "Please enter a quantity value";


                else:
                    $bequan = test_input($_POST["bequan"]);
                    if ($bequan <= 0):
                        $bequanerr = "Please enter a valid quantity value greater than 0";

                    else:
                        if (empty($_POST["ber"])):
                            $ber = 400;
                            echo "400";
                        else:
                            $ber = test_input($_POST["ber"]);

                        endif;
                        if (empty($_POST["bes"])):
                            $bes = 0;
                        else:
                            $bes = test_input($_POST["bes"]);
                        endif;
                    endif;

                    echo $ber . " " . $bes . " " . $bequan;
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

                endif;
            endif;

        endif;

        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
        ?>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button> 
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/powerforlight.jpg" style= "max-height:50px; margin-top:-14px; "/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a class="" href="vendorcf.php">Vendor Contact Form</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a class="" href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form  name="myForm" class="form-horizontal " role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"  autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                            <h2 class="text-center">Bootstrap Design table</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">          
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>        
                                            <th rowspan="2">Household Items</th>
                                            <th colspan="2">Running Wattage

                                            </th>
                                            <th colspan="2">Starting Wattage

                                            </th>
                                            <th rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
                                            <th rowspan="2">Should start Parallely</th>
                                            <th rowspan="2">Should start Serially</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Typical
                                            </th>
                                            <th> Specific </th>


                                            <th>
                                                Typical
                                            </th>
                                            <th> Specific </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="bechk" value="be" <?php if (isset($bechk) && $bechk == "be") echo "checked"; ?>>Blanket, Electric
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td name="be1">400</td>
                                            <td><input type="number" name="ber" /> </td>
                                            <td name="be2">0</td>
                                            <td><input type="number" name="bes" /> </td>
                                            <td><input type="number" name="bequan" value="<?php echo $bequan; ?>"/> 
                                                <p style="color:red"> <?php echo $bequanerr; ?></p></td>
                                            <td><input type="radio" name= "berad" class="rdo"  value="P" <?php if (isset($berad) && $berad == "P") echo "checked"; ?> />  </td>
                                            <td><input type="radio" name= "berad" class="rdo"  value="S" <?php if (isset($berad) && $berad == "S") echo "checked"; ?> />  </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="controls col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="reg">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you changed/why OP should use that code would be nice.

Comment: I just make changes in the code. Adding some variables and conditions that's it.